# Tkinter text binding without button press or click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Tkinter ScrolledText widget which is intended to pop-up (after clicking another button) to display various information from another function.

Right now, the Text widget pops up and displays, but it requires a "click" to initiate.

```
    self.output_field.bind("<1>", self._set_focus_output_field)

    self.input_field.bind("<Return>", self.process_command)
```

How can I have the text widget mimic the "click" automatically, but only do so once? (I don't want the other function being called repeatedly. Just once to have that information display).

Comment: If the popup is supposed to happen on a different button click, what's stopping you from putting the popup action in the first button's callback?

Comment: @ScottLawson Ignorance about how to do this :P

Comment: I think I'm a little bit confused about what your GUI is supposed to do. Your question title says you want the text to appear without a button press or click, but your question says that this is going to happen "after clicking another button". What is the exact action that is supposed to trigger this popup?

Comment: @ScottLawson My bad. I have a button called "Device Information". When I hit this button a pop-up with the scrolledtext widget appears. Right now I also have to click into the scrolledtext for the other function call that pulls information to be set off.

I'd like for it to avoid that extra last step.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? I'll be able to help you better if I can see the code for the button and for the scrolledtext widget.